# Objectify : is there a way to know whether the entity is loaded from objectify session or directly from datastore?

Tags: objectify

I have two question :

1) Suppose i have already loaded 50 entities from datastore using a set of filters and it would be present in the objectify session, after a while, if i try to load the same entities with a different set of filters would it fetch from objectify session or datastore?

2) I have 50 entities already loaded and is available in objectify session, now am trying to load some entities with a set of filters , for example this filter would fetch 55 entities, out of that 50 entities will be the same that i have already loaded, the other 5 are a new ones. Will it fetch all 55 entities from datastore or will it fetch 50 entities from session and the remaining 5 from datastore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objectify always prefers to give you objects from the session. The answer to 1 is that you will get objects from the session. The answer to 2 is you will get (as many as possible) objects from the session.

Keep in mind that queries (ie not get-by-key operations) always reach to the datastore to execute. Depending on a variety of factors, Objectify might issue a keys-only query and then perform a batch get-by-key for any "missing" entities, or Objectify might issue a full query and throw out any extra data which is already present in the session.

Comment: Ohh, my queries are not get-by-key ops, all of my queries are based on the fields of the entity, so even if the same entities are present in session, it would still hit datastore isn't it? Thank you for clearing my doubt !! @stickfigure

Comment: The query parser and all logic to determine if an entity matches a query is handled by the datastore server-side. So queries must hit the server to identify the result set. Sometimes Objectify can "hybridize" the query by making it keys-only, but the index only exists on the datastore itself.